# Incoming soap message exception: No adapter for endpoint;Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-boot, apache-camel, soapui

Application using spring-boot. for a soap webservice incoming message, I am getting following error while using through soapUI.
No adapter for endpoint [public boolean com.company...putMessage(com.company...MessageRequest)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?

===============

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NSURI, localPart = "MessageRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public boolean putMessage(@RequestPayload MessageRequest message) {
    return myServiceImplementaion.putMessage(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using spring boot annotation configuration? If so, try adding this to your configuration file,

```
@Bean
    public EndpointAdapter payloadEndpointAdapter() {
        return new PayloadEndpointAdapter();
    }
```